# Change colour of selected value of sidebar in Angular 6

Tags: css, angular, html, typescript, angular-forms

I want to change the colour of the selected value of the sidebar.

#### Template

```
<div class="card c-setting">
  <div class="card-header" title="Data Loader"(click)="clickDataloader()">
  <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" >
     <span><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>  
     <span>Data Loader</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

#### Typescript

```
 clickDataloader(){
   this.DataLoader = false
   this.setting = true
   this.userManagement = true
   this.header = "Data Loader"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the css for the selected values, by adding these css code in .css file of the component.

```
/* unvisited value */
a:link {
 color: green;
}

/* visited value */
a:visited {
 color: green;
}

/* mouse over value */
a:hover {
 color: red;
}

/* selected value */
a:active {
 color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: can you share reproduce your error in codepen or jsfiddle or somewhere else